# How to find exact match using strpos?

Tags: php

If I look out for `war` that would also be found if I check `Award`:

```
 $title = "Music award";
 if (strpos($title, 'war') !== false) {
    echo "found";
  }
```

If I look for `war` I don't want to find `award`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to match and not to match? If you need an _exact_ match,  that would imply to me to simply compare with `===` instead of `strpos()`. Do you want to match an exact _word_ as a substring? That may not be doable with `strpos()` requiring a regular expression instead.

Comment: `preg_match('/\war\b/',$title)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski update the question if that helps

Comment: @Federkun so `if (preg_match('/\War\b/', $title) !== false) {` ?

Comment: As suggested above, why can't you just do a `===` check?

Comment: @Script47 I don't the answer but by looking at other answers on stack and online, looks like `preg_match` is the way to go.. maybe some else could reply to your quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex matching

```
$title = "Music award";
if (preg_match('/\bwar\b/', $title) !== false) {
    echo "found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = "We are the music makers and we are the dreamers of dreams.";
$words  = str_word_count($string, 1);
var_dump(in_array('music', $words));
var_dump(in_array('dream', $words));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```